# How to make a permutation code more concise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For Example, I have A,B,C,D. It could be true or false  input and every statement has it own condition, so I need to write 2^4=16 if-else statements, but it looks too messy

I only know the brute force solution...

ABCD

ABC

ABD

ACD

BCD

AB

AC

CD

BC

BD

A

B

C

D

nothing

```
const  Permutations = (A,B,C,D) => {

    if (!A && !B && !C && !D) {
        return '1'
    } else if (!A && B && !C && !D) {
        return '2'
    } else if (!A && !B && C && !D) {
        return '3'
    } else if (!A && !B && !C && D) {
        return '4'
    } else if (A && B && !C && !D) {
        return '5'
    } else if (!A && B && !C && D) {
        return '6'
    } else if (!A && B && C && !D) {
        return '7'
    } else if (A && !B && !C && D) {
        return '8'
    } else if (A && !B && C && !D) {
        return '9'
    } else if (!A && !B && C && !D) {
        return '10'
    } else if (A && !B && C && D) {
        return '11'
    } else if (!A && B && C && D) {
        return '12'
    } else if (A && B && !C && D) {
        return '13'
    } else if (A && B && C && !D) {
        return "14"
    } else if (A && B && C && D) {
        return "15"
    }else{
      return '16'
    }
}



 Permutations(true,true,true,true)
```

I hope the code can be more concise and not include 16 if-else statements.

Comment: It just depends on what the order your variables are in - do you want to check how many variables are true or false? That would be much easier.

Comment: The variable is true or false

Comment: If there are 16 possibilities of inputs and each possibility needs to have a different outcome, I'm not sure what else you can do. You COULD have nested if statements to make the code easier to trace and understand, but it could also make it more complicated and confusing to create.

Comment: It's difficult to tell from looking at the code, but it looks like you're basically converting a 4-bit value encoded in four booleans to a string representation of its base 10 equivalent. (Plus `1`.)

Comment: @DaveNewton and it looks to be in little endian format too from what I can tell.

Comment: @Steve was thinking the same, but then (!A && !B && C && !D) {  return '3' } doesn't make sense as 0010 would then be 8, no?

Comment: @exside I can't see any pattern in the code, it looks like the author just wants to map each combination of booleans to a unique value.

Comment: @exside good catch. I only looked at the first 2 and assumed the pattern continued.

Comment: So 16 = A & !B & !C & !D ? Or this is 1 and u made a mistake, and all false are 16 ?

Comment: If you look closer, condition for 10 is the the same than for 3. Surely a mistake...

Comment: the reason I use 1~16 in return just an example, the real code will be I need to do different thing in the return, to run different number

Comment: ... And this is why we provide actual examples. I'd probably just create an object or `Map` with the concatenated values as the key, and do whatever you want for the values, e.g., could be functions, values, whatever. It's a basic command table. You could programmatically generate the outline of the object and fill in the values. Or use a trie, or nested objects, or whatever. But without a realistic example to work from, it's hard to say what would work "best".

Answer (score 3):

You can parse your arguments as a binary string and convert it to get all permutations as a unique integer value :

```js
const Permutations = (A, B, C, D) => {
  A = A ? '1' : '0';
  B = B ? '1' : '0';
  C = C ? '1' : '0';
  D = D ? '1' : '0';

  return parseInt(`${D}${C}${B}${A}`, 2) + 1;
}

console.log(Permutations(false, false, false, false)); // 1
console.log(Permutations(true, false, false, false)); // 2
console.log(Permutations(false, true, false, false)); // 3
console.log(Permutations(true, true, false, false)); // 4
console.log(Permutations(false, false, true, false)); // 5
console.log(Permutations(true, false, true, false)); // 6
console.log(Permutations(false, true, true, false)); // 7
console.log(Permutations(true, true, true, false)); // 8
console.log(Permutations(false, false, false, true)); // 9
console.log(Permutations(true, false, false, true)); // 10
console.log(Permutations(false, true, false, true)); // 11
console.log(Permutations(false, false, true, true)); // 12
console.log(Permutations(true, true, false, true)); // 13
console.log(Permutations(true, false, true, true)); // 14
console.log(Permutations(false, true, true, true)); // 15
console.log(Permutations(true, true, true, true)); // 16
```

Comment: Could also be written as: `const Permutations = function(A,B,C,D) {
  return parseInt(Array.from(arguments).map(arg => Number(arg)).reverse().join(''), 2)+1;
}`

Answer (score 1):

I would use flags for this, but it would require you to use different return values:

```
const permutations = (A,B,C,D) => {
    let flags = 0;

    if (A) { flags ^= 0x1; }
    if (B) { flags ^= 0x2; }
    if (C) { flags ^= 0x4; }
    if (D) { flags ^= 0x8; }

    return flags;
}

permutations(false, false, false, false); // 0

permutations(true, false, false, false);  // 1
permutations(false, true, false, false);  // 2
permutations(true, true, false, false);   // 3
permutations(false, false, true, false);  // 4
permutations(true, false, true, false);   // 5
permutations(false, true, true, false);   // 6
permutations(true, true, true, false);    // 7
permutations(false, false, false, true);  // 8
permutations(true, false, false, true);   // 9
permutations(false, true, false, true);   // 10
permutations(true, true, false, true);    // 11
permutations(false, false, true, true);   // 12
permutations(true, false, true, true);    // 13
permutations(false, true, true, true);    // 14
permutations(true, true, true, true);     // 15
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the prettiest way I can come up with. However, it's up to you to put the values in `results` in the correct order, and it doesn't show the expected outcomes very clearly.

```
function permutations(...bools) {
    let results = [
        'result 1',
        'result 2',
        'result 3',
        'result 4',
        'result 5',
        'result 6',
        'result 7',
        'result 8',
        'result 9',
        'result 10',
        'result 11',
        'result 12',
        'result 13',
        'result 14',
        'result 15',
        'result 16',
    ];

    return results[Number('0b' + bools.map(bool => Number(bool)).join(''))];
}
```

Comment: This assumes you want unique values. If you just want the numbers you could do that in one line using what I did the in last line of the function and adding `1`.

Answer (score 0):

With this, you can have as many arguments as you want.

```js
const Permutations = (...args) =>
    parseInt(args.map(a => a ? '1': '0').join(''), 2);

console.log(Permutations(false, true, false));
console.log(Permutations(true, false, true, true));
console.log(Permutations(false, true, true, false, true));
console.log(Permutations(true, true, true, true, false, false));
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't reduce your program complexity but will maybe make it more readable by treating the logic like what it really is: a lookup table:

```
var map = {
    '0000': 1,
    '0100': 2,
    '0010': 3,
    '0001': 4,
    '1100': 5,
    '0101': 6,
    '0110': 7,
    '1001': 8,
    '1010': 9,
    '0010': 10,
    '1011': 11,
    '0111': 12,
    '1101': 13,
    '1110': 14,
    '1111': 15
}

var key = (A ? '1' : '0') +
          (B ? '1' : '0') +
          (C ? '1' : '0') +
          (D ? '1' : '0');

var result = map[key];

return result === undefined ? 16 : result;
```

Now, just looking at this `map` it is easier to see that your original code has a bug:

```
'0010': 3,
'0010': 10,
```

So it's already better than the original code in making bugs more obvious. By re-arranging the keys in binary order we can figure out what the bug is:

```
var map = {
    '0000': 1,
    '0001': 4,
    '0010': 3,
    '0010': 10, // duplicate
                // 0011 is missing
    '0100': 2,
    '0101': 6,
    '0110': 7,
    '0111': 12,
                // 1000 is missing
    '1001': 8,
    '1010': 9,
    '1011': 11,
    '1100': 5,
    '1101': 13,
    '1110': 14,
    '1111': 15
}
```

So it turns out you have two bugs. Personally for me this makes this style of coding significantly better because it allows you to more easily debug your logic

---

#### Bonus trick

If you don't care about what number each key produce but only need the number to be unique (eg: it's OK if `!A,!B,!C,!D` returns `0` instead of `1`) then there is a simple trick to convert the booleans to a number:

```
var key = (A ? '1' : '0') +
          (B ? '1' : '0') +
          (C ? '1' : '0') +
          (D ? '1' : '0');

return parseInt(key, 2); // the 2 makes it treat the number as binary
```

Answer (score 0):

People often use arrays to solve this sort of problem. Make sure to initialize properly if you are using multidimensional arrays.

```
results[0][0][0][0] = 'result 1'
results[0][0][0][1] = 'result 2'
results[0][0][1][0] = 'result 3'


return results[A][B][C][D];
```

Or you can just use a separator and concatenate the keys to make a main key.

```
return results[ A + '|' + B + '|' + C + '|' + D]
```